# Functions and global scope/nested function confusion in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, scope, global

```
fridge={"cheese":10, "milk":11, "feta":12, "cream":21, "onion":32, "pepper":25} 
def fridge_function (fridge):
    del fridge["feta"]

    return

print (fridge)
```

I am confused.

1) I thought that the dictionary had global scope.

2) What I am trying to do is remove items from the dictionary, then update the amended dictionary as appropriate, i.e. remove the value "feta".

3) When I print fridge, I get the original list, in its unedited version. I even tried making a copy of the fridge, then trying to print that value outside of the function, but, the end result was the same: the original fridge dictionary with no modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `fridge` in as a parameter, ergo it's going to be a local variable. To use the global `fridge` you would do:

```
FRIDGE = {"cheese": 10, "milk": 11, "feta": 12, "cream": 21, "onion": 32, "pepper": 25}

def fridge_function():
    del FRIDGE["feta"]

fridge_function()   # you need to call it
print(FRIDGE)
```

globals would normally be upper cased, so I've called the variable `FRIDGE`.

You'll need to add the `global` statement if you need to *assign* to the global variable (and only then):

```
def myfunction():
    global MYGLOBAL
    MYGLOBAL = 42
```

Using globals, and functions that mutate globals, are usually not a good solution however. Perhaps something object-oriented would be better? (Python 2.7 syntax):

```
class Fridge(dict):
    def __init__(self, **contents):
        super(Fridge, self).__init__(contents)

def main():
    fridge = Fridge(
        cheese=10,
        milk=11,
        feta=12,
        cream=21,
        onion=32,
        pepper=25
    )
    print fridge
    del fridge['feta']
    print fridge

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the output is

```
{'cheese': 10, 'pepper': 25, 'feta': 12, 'onion': 32, 'milk': 11, 'cream': 21}
{'cheese': 10, 'pepper': 25, 'onion': 32, 'milk': 11, 'cream': 21}
```

Comment: You stated "globals would normally be upper cased" such as FRIDGE.

is that purely a aesthetic convention to improve visibility/readability, or is an actual requirement of the code?

Comment: Yes, per PEP8 (the python style guide): https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The convention in PEP8 is to use all-caps for constants, not globals.

Comment: @Stuart it seems may be technically correct (and that's the best kind of correct), however `pylint` requires all globals to be upper-case and I think most everyone uses upper case for all globals.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't called the function *fridge_function* with *fridge*

This should work:

```
fridge_function(fridge)
print (fridge)
```

Comment: And the function does not need the return statement :)

Comment: I thought all functions required return as part of their syntax....? :O

Comment: Actually, all functions in Python returns something... if the return statement is omitted, the function returns None by default ;)

Comment: Here, take this http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html :) happy learning :D

Answer (score 2):

For further clarification, note that either of the following will work:

With `fridge` as a function parameter:

```
fridge={"cheese":10, "milk":11, "feta":12, "cream":21, "onion":32, "pepper":25} 
def fridge_function(fridge):
    del fridge["feta"]  # reference to fridge passed as a parameter

fridge_function(fridge)
print(fridge)
```

With `fridge` as a global variable

```
fridge={"cheese":10, "milk":11, "feta":12, "cream":21, "onion":32, "pepper":25} 
def fridge_function():
    del fridge["feta"]  # refers to the global fridge 

fridge_function()
print(fridge)
```

The first is considered better programming style in most cases, as [global variables are usually best avoided](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime).